# Reinitialize third party keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, high-sierra, usb, hardware

Is there any way to reinitialize an external third party USB keyboard? I hit a wrong key after MACOS detected the new keyboard hardware. Now, my keymapping is not correct.

I need to remove or reinitialize it (repeating the hardware detection).

Any ideas?

Comment: Tell us what the right and wrong keymappings are that you are referring to.

Comment: See this note for more info on changing the keyboard type   https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html

Comment: Great. That solved my problem. I wrote it down as general solution.

Comment: This happens a lot for me - the ` and \ keys get swapped.  Annoyingly the Change Keyboard Type button in Keyboard preferences disappears when I need it to fix this.  Still an issue with Mojave. Luckily the answer from @berlin104 resolves that problem and allows setting the Keyboard Type as ISO which fixes things.

Comment: I have discovered that I can bring the Change Keyboard Type button back by clicking the Set Up Bluetooth Keyboard button and removing my keyboard, then reconnecting it.  This does bring the button back but clicking on it does nothing - in console I see an entry for KeyboardSetupAssistant that says "No unknown keyboard connected - terminating". Looks like fixing this always requires a reboot. How annoying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution. If anyone stumbles over this thread (Thanks to TOM - see: https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html):

Remove the keyboard file (see command), unplug the USB keyboard and reboot. Reconnect the keyboard which opens the keyboard detection assistant.

Command:

```
rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist
```

Answer (score 3):

Try going to System Preferences -> Keyboard and click the "Change Keyboard Type..." button in the lower left corner. This should restart the keyboard type detection.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I already tried this, but it seems that the button don't work. Nothing happens when I trigger it.

Comment: @berlin104 Hm, strange. For me it opens a new window with the Keyboard Setup Assistant and lets me continue to setup the keyboard again. Might it be that the window pops up underneath another or off screen?

Comment: Jap. That's really strange... I don't see this button always. Seems that it appears random.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but the Change Keyboard Type button is often missing, so berlin104's answer is the one that works in that case.